# setting up MediaWiki to host more than one wiki

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, mediawiki

I am working on `Ubuntu` and have no experience in about `PHP` or `Apache`. Now I want to setup a `wiki-family`. So I looked to the official docs [Manual:Wiki family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family). There are some steps to do that. I could do first 5 steps but 6th step(Creating a LocalSettings.php) has two options and I do not understand what those mean:

- If you have different (sub)domains that link to one directory on your server
- If your wikis are on the same domain but different paths (e.g. yourdomain.com/wiki1, yourdomain.com/wiki2 etc)

What are `wikis`? Are they directories? LocalSettings.php? Or ...?

Also I saw these options [here](https://booleandreams.files.wordpress.com/2007/06/multiple-mediawiki-instance-on-the-same-server-using-the-same-source-code.pdf):

- First of all you can have wikis are in different directories or sub domains
  linked to the same directory on our server
- We have different domains that link to one directory on your server

It seems recent options are different. What those options mean and how I can select between them?

Answer (score 2):

The point 6 explains that you have two options based in the url that you want to use.

The two options, translated into url's, are:

1. wiki1.yourdomain.com wiki2.yourdomain.com
2. yourdomain.com/wiki1 yourdomain.com/wiki2

Wikis are all the wikis that you want to host with only one installation.

In layman's terms, if you follow the [official guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family) you will have:

- One installation in one directory.
- Multiple LocalSettings_wiki.php files (one for every wiki)
- One -and only- LocalSettings.php that will include the modifications explained in the point 6 in [Manual:Wiki Family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a guide to running multiple wiki's out of one directory (folder). It would appear that you can use mediawiki to accomplish this by having multiple LocalSettings_x.php files, defined in a main LocalSettings.php file.

So, you would have a LocalSettings.php file that stores global settings and also points to LocalSettings_wiki1.php and LocalSettings_wiki2.php.

From my understanding, all of these would be in the same directory.

**In the case of the virtual subfolder**

I don't think Apache needs to be aware, it looks like you can define mydomain.com/wiki1 within the php files, and the wiki will "know" how to handle this.

**In the case of subdomain**

(wiki1.youromain.com, wiki2.yourdomain.com) Apache config is needed, it needs to be told to point to the proper place, this is accomplished with [Apache virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html).

Your case might look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/mediawiki"
ServerName wiki1.mydomain.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/mediawiki"
ServerName wiki2.mydomain.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

The confusion in this setup you're running everything out of 1 folder, with virtual url paths. For example, a visitor would type mydomain.com/wiki2, but /var/www/wiki2 would not exist on your server, it would be directed behind the scenes as defined by LocalSettings.php

N.B. This is a a theoretical answer to the question, as I have no experience with Mediawiki and limited experience configuring apache. I will edit as needed.